# window.print() without printers causes the main process to crash in Electron App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I'm using Electron with react-js. whenever I call `window.print()` it shows the popup but if I tries to close it, it causes a crash and the whole window closed automatically.

```
btn.onClick = (e) => { 
    e.preventDefault
    window.print()
}

/* dependencies */
'version' : '17.0.1' ,
"react": "^17.0.2" ,
"electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0"
```

> So, my question is how to fix it in the Electron app, and can I use silent print in react-js if yes how I can use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I ended up with a solution. I visit the  [Electron site](https://www.electronjs.org/releases/stable) they just released a new stable version of electron `17.1.1` and they also have been fixed this issue. it's working fine in my device **window 10**

> Type `npm i electon@latest` it'll install a newer version of Electron.